# Dual space of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis

In combinatorics class which I sat in on, my professor started lecturing about “Frechét algebras” while we were on the subject of generating functions. Although I understood very little of what was going on, he did say something interesting:

The dual space of $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ is $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Why is that?